# How to serialize duplicate XML elements into an array?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-core, xml-serialization

I'm attempting to serialize some poorly formatted XML. I'm specifically having issues converting duplicate elements into an array.

In usual cases, something like this would serialize just fine

**Class**

```
public class Animal
{
    [XmlArray("Dogs")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Dog", typeof(Dog))]
    public Dog[] Dogs {get;set;}
}
```

**XML**

```
<Animals>
    <Dogs>
        <Dog>
            <Name>Spot</Name>
            <Age>5</Age>
        </Dog>
        <Dog>
            <Name>Spike</Name>
            <Age>2</Age>
        </Dog>
        <Dog>
            <Name>Arnold</Name>
            <Age>7</Age>
        </Dog>
    </Dogs>
</Animals>
```

**In reality, the XML is structured as follows**

```
<Animals>
    <Dog>
        <Name>Spot</Name>
        <Age>5</Age>
    </Dog>
    <Dog>
        <Name>Spike</Name>
        <Age>2</Age>
    </Dog>
    <Dog>
        <Name>Arnold</Name>
        <Age>7</Age>
    </Dog>
</Animals>
```

What's the easiest way I can serialize these properties into an array?

Answer (score 0):

It should work as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes#serializing-an-array-as-a-sequence-of-elements i.e.

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "Dog")]
public Dog[] Dogs {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't contain code of serializing method. Anyway, the XML markup described above should work when using the following serializing method:

```cs
public class Animals
{
    [XmlArray("Dogs")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Dog", typeof(Dog))]
    public Dog[] Dogs { get; set; }
}

public static string SerializeToXml(object o)
{          
    var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { Ident=true, XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
    using (var stream = new StringWriter())
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true }))
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Animals));
        serializer.Serialize(writer, o, ns);
        return stream.ToString();
    }
}
```

The test code

```cs
var animals = new Animals()
    {
        Dogs = new Dog[] { new Dog { Name = "dog1", Age = 6 }, new Dog { Name = "dog2", Age = 7 } }
    };

var xml = SerializeToXml(animals);
```

will produce the following XML:

```xml
<Animals>
  <Dogs>
    <Dog>
      <Name>dog1</Name>
      <Age>6</Age>
    </Dog>
    <Dog>
      <Name>dog2</Name>
      <Age>7</Age>
    </Dog>
  </Dogs>
</Animals>
```

For additional information see [Serializing an Array of Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization#serializing-an-array-of-objects).